# I need to be able to understand how to javascript a html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've been working with my website and I can't find out how to make a javascript work with my HTML page
```./index.HTML``

Comment: Is PHP involved? What have you tried? (Posting `./index.HTML` isn't enough info) What doesn't work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript has tutorials

Answer (score 1):

make a file with .js. there comes your java script in.
in the file.html you put a line called script to the end of the body.

```
<html>
<body>

//** your code **//

<script src="/assets/js/your-java-script-file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```